# .htcaccess rewrite rules not working on localhost

Tags: url-rewriting, localhost, apache2

I'm working on a mvc php project but i'm having trouble with the .htcaccess file.
I want to rout everything trough index.php. But when i type http://localhost/mvc/public/test.php it doens't redirect to index.php, it displays an error 404 and when i type http://localhost/mvc/public/index.php?url=test.php it works. Btw i'm really new to mvc and routing.

```
.htcaccess code:
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
      Options -Multiviews
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /mvc/public
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: You should be aiming to do `/mvc/public/test` not `/mvc/public/test.php`, in your router prepend the `.php` from `?url=` value. Though it sounds like your doing a `include($_GET['url'])`, which is bad MVC design, you shouldn't be loading files based on the route but instead calling the controller methods, at no point should the value be used to load files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at last line:

```
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ /mvc/public/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```